# How to Unit Test when the WPF Application is needed?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, xaml, applicationcontext

I need to test my library with Unit Testing.

Unfortunately the library takes as a parameter a System.Windows.Application instance. Normally in the real world WPF application this would be the `public partial class App : Application` entry `App.xaml` application class.

This is needed for the `DispatcherUnhandledException` event that the library uses to register a handler.

Is there a way to mock or to initialize the `Application.Current`, which is null in a WPF Unit Test library?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap it with another class implementing an interface. When unit testing inject the mock implementation.

```
public interface IExceptionManager
{
    event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler DispatcherUnhandledException;
}

public class ExceptionManager : IExceptionManager
{
    Application _app;

    public ExceptionManager(Application app)
    {
        _app = app;
    }

    public event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler DispatcherUnhandledException
    {
        add
        {
            _app.DispatcherUnhandledException += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            _app.DispatcherUnhandledException -= value;
        }
    }
}

public class MockExceptionManager: IExceptionManager
{
    public event DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler DispatcherUnhandledException;
}
```

Comment: This might be the efficient way I was looking for. Will refactor and try to my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... Usually this is what your App.xaml.cs looks like (I've added a property that you can access, but disregard it if you don't need it):

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
            ExampleProp = "whatever floats your boat here";

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// You can access this from any class by using "App.ExampleProp".
        /// </summary>
        public static string ExampleProp{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, you can access this from any place using the *"App.MyExampleProp"*, but more to the point, since App extends Application, it also have App.Current, which is what you were after, letting you access the current application.

Comment: And how this would be useful to use in a Unit Test library project? I miss something.

Comment: You were asking about accessing the Application. With the extra info you gave, maxim answers seems like the way to go.